# Запись изменена другим пользователем

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте. Необходима помощь с корректировкой селекта (прошу не кидаться камнями из за возможно албанских вопросов, но я далек от программирования и связался с этим в виду обстоятельств (временное отсутствие специально обученного человека в отделе на предприятии))
Селект таблицы. Изначально выглядел след. образом

```
select t.id,
       t.journal_id,
       t.equipment_id,
       t.operation_id,
       t.operation2_id,
       t.protocol_id,
       t.department_id,
       t.section_id,
       t.metrology_user_id,
       t.main_date,
       t.eq_name,
       t.eq_type,
       t.eq_factory_number,
       t.in_emp_fio,
       t.control_date,
       t.control_result,
       t.out_date,
       t.out_emp_fio,
       t.doc_num,
       t.control_doc_num,
       t.asu_tp_iis_system_id,
       t.control_user_id,
       t.control_type,
       t.report_num,
       t.equipment_cnt,
       e.control_executer_id,
       t.control_executer,
       case when t.out_date is not null and t.out_emp_fio is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_signed,
       t.rowid,
       :buro_id as buro_id,
       :j_user_id as j_user_id,
       :j_type as j_type,
       case when t.doc_num not like 
           decode(j.dic_control_type_id, 3, '072/È-03-___-____', 
                 '072/' || buro_id || '-' || j.num || '-___%-____') 
       then 1 else 0 end as wrong_doc_num,
       case when :j_type = 2 and t.report_num not like 
           decode(j.dic_control_type_id, 3, '072/È-02-___-____',
                 '072/' || buro_id || '-' || j.num || '-___%-____') 
       then 1 else 0 end as wrong_report_num
  from metrology.journal_line t
  join (select id, num, buro_id, dic_control_type_id from metrology.journal) j on j.id = t.journal_id 
  left join (select id, control_executer_id from metrology.equipment) e on e.id = t.equipment_id
 where (JOURNAL_ID = :JOURNAL_ID)
   and (:not_out = 0 or t.out_date is null or :j_type not in (1, 4))
   and (:control_happened = 0 or t.control_date is not null or :j_type != 1)
 order by main_date desc
```

Все работало, однако при опр. установках (journal_id = 1157, ид необходимого журнала для внесения записи) в поле

```
t.control_doc_num
```

Не подтягивался необходимый номер документа. Худо-бедно я воткнул вместо этого поля "костыль", заменив его на

```
decode(t.journal_id, 1157, 
       (select o.report_num from metrology.operation o
        where o.op_date = t.control_date
    and o.equipment_id = t.equipment_id
    and o.metrology_user_id = t.metrology_user_id 
    and o.control_type = t.control_type),
    t.control_doc_num) as control_doc_num
```

И вуаля! Необходимый номер документа подтянулся, и впринципе вроде как все работает. Однако теперь при попытке удаления записи с подтянутым таким образом номером документа появляется сообщение: "Запись изменена другим пользователем. Изменились поля" и наименование поля (control_doc_num). Как я понимаю, это sql ошибка, однако в интернетах ничего конкретного по ее исправлению не нашел. Буду премного благодарен за помощь в исправлении, или совете, каким образом можно еще реализовать необходимое.

Comment: Нет - это ошибка не SQL а вашего клиента, который делает запись. Возможно стоило бы указать чем вы пользуетесь. PowerBuilder например умеет выдавать подобные ошибки. Он в запросе на обновление в where перечисляет все предыдущие значения колонок. и убеждается что запись не изменилась пока он ее правил. Учитывая, что данное поле у вас в любом случае вычисляемое  и берется не из основной таблицы и обновлять его явно не надо исключите его из списка изменяемых полей в форме

Comment: Откровенно в этом слаб, но вроде как C++ билдер. Стесняюсь спросить, но все же - каким образом можно исключить данное поле?

Comment: В C++ не представляю. В PB при сохранении DW он предварительно открывал экран с настройками записи формы и там можно было мышкой отметить те поля которые надо писать в update. Раз после редактирования формы у вас это поле попало в update значит у вас там есть что то подобное и где то в настройках грида или через что там у вас идет обновление БД должно это быть

Comment: В общем в "клиенте" поставил отметку в свойствах поля - обрабатывать на сервере. Поля удаляются, спасибо за подсказку.